# NetApp: How to get real file's access time (atime) from a snapshot?

Tags: network-attached-storage, snapshot, netapp

According to the documentation (https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1635994/html/GUID-3CE08FEA-6624-4EBF-847C-F7F9C7F355A3.html) access time of all files in the snapshot copy is set to snapshot creation time. Is there a way to get the original atime?

Comment: Maybe the atime is available via an API call or f-policy?